# React UI is not updating

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object, local-storage, mapping

On every action I am pushing new array of object in the local storage. After that I am mapping over the localstorage data. Now the problem is the UI is not updating autometicaly on every new data inserted to the array of object. But I can see new data on every manual refresh.

Hare is the data I am inserting into the local storage:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const input = e.target.input.value;
    chatLog.push({ user: "Me", text: `${input}` });
    localStorage.setItem("chatLog", JSON.stringify(chatLog));
}
```

Here I have mapped the data in anorther component:

```
const chatLog = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("chatLog"));
  return (
    <div>
      {chatLog.map((message) => (
        <div
          className={`chat ${
            message.user === "Me" ? "chat-end" : "chat-start"
          }`}
        >
          <div className="chat-image avatar">
            <div className="w-10 rounded-full">
              <img
                src={message.user === "Me" ? Me : Rakib}
                alt={message.user === "Me" ? "user" : "rakib"}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="chat-header">{message.user}</div>
          <div className="chat-bubble">{message.text}</div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

Now I want that, Everytime the localStorage get new data. Then the UI will update autometicaly.

Comment: chatLog is not reactive. you need to use `const [chatlog, setChatlog] = React.useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("chatLog")))`. And update it with: `setChatlog((prev) => [...prev, { user: "Me", text: input}])` (instead of `chaLog.push(...)`).

Answer (score 0):

When new data is added to the localStorage, you need to use some state management solution like React's state or a third-party library like Redux.

One way to achieve this is to use React's state to store the chatLog data and update it whenever a new message is added to the localStorage. Example:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function ChatLog() {
  const [chatLog, setChatLog] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("chatLog")) || []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleStorageChange = (e) => {
      if (e.key === "chatLog") {
        setChatLog(JSON.parse(e.newValue));
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("storage", handleStorageChange);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("storage", handleStorageChange);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const input = e.target.input.value;
    const newMessage = { user: "Me", text: `${input}` };
    chatLog.push(newMessage);
    localStorage.setItem("chatLog", JSON.stringify(chatLog));
    setChatLog([...chatLog, newMessage]);
    e.target.reset();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {chatLog.map((message, index) => (
        <div
          key={index}
          className={`chat ${
            message.user === "Me" ? "chat-end" : "chat-start"
          }`}
        >
          <div className="chat-image avatar">
            <div className="w-10 rounded-full">
              <img
                src={message.user === "Me" ? Me : Rakib}
                alt={message.user === "Me" ? "user" : "rakib"}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="chat-header">{message.user}</div>
          <div className="chat-bubble">{message.text}</div>
        </div>
      ))}
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" name="input" />
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```